# Expo React Native error: Unhandled JS Exception: manifest must specify logUrl

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

When publishing my app with expo using `expo publish` or pushing the app to App Store and Play Store, I get a crash on launch of the production app on both iOS and Android plateform with the error :

> Unhandled JS Exception: manifest must specify logUrl

As this error doesn't happened on Development app, I don't know how to debug this. Does anyone encounter the same issue ? Do you have any idea on what's going on or do you have any idea on a method to find the error ?

Just for more context, I did publish my app to both stores months ago without any issue. I did not change anything in my manifest except changing the Expo SDK from version 38 to 40. Here is my current manifest :

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My App",
    "slug": "myApp",
    "privacy": "public",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
    "primaryColor": "#7198FF",
    "icon": "./assets/android-icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/Launch_Screen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.company.app",
      "buildNumber": "1"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.company.app",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "MANAGE_DOCUMENTS",
        "READ_CONTACTS",
        "READ_CALENDAR",
        "WRITE_CALENDAR",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "READ_PHONE_STATE",
        "RECORD_AUDIO",
        "USE_FINGERPRINT",
        "VIBRATE"
      ],
      "versionCode": 21
    },
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "visible": "sticky-immersive",
      "barStyle": "dark-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "hidden": false,
      "translucent": true,
      "barStyle": "dark-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "extra": {
      "firebase": {
        "apiKey": "FIREBASE_KEY",
        "authDomain": "app.firebaseapp.com",
        "databaseURL": "https://app.firebaseio.com",
        "projectId": "app",
        "storageBucket": "app.appspot.com",
        "messagingSenderId": "SENDER_ID",
        "appId": "1:appID",
        "measurementId": "G-ID"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "config": {
        "firebase": {
          "apiKey": "FIREBASE_KEY",
          "authDomain": "app.firebaseapp.com",
          "databaseURL": "https://app.firebaseio.com",
          "projectId": "app",
          "storageBucket": "app.appspot.com",
          "messagingSenderId": "MESSEGING_ID",
          "appId": "1:APP_ID:web:WEB_ID",
          "measurementId": "G-ID"
        }
      }
    },
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "app",
            "project": "app",
            "authToken": "SENTRY_TOKEN"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: must be something specified to config files, as manifest is referenced to app.json or something similar [check here](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/?redirected)

Comment: I agree @Oleksii, it's probably an issue in the app.js file (witch I detailed in the question). However, the 'logUrl' field that the error say is missing can not be added by myself. I tried and it gives me an error right on build time.

Comment: seems like expo tries to put logs somewhere on production, do you have `Logs.enableExpoCliLogging();` enabled? Or if not, try manually importing logs at entry point `import { Logs } from 'expo';` and manually disabling them 
`Logs.disableExpoCliLogging(); ` maybe this way no logs will be printed if you had any, and thus no logUrl will be called, if neither works, i advise to open an issue since this looks like version specific

Comment: Ohhhhh !… @Oleksii You're right ! I did enable Expo CLI logging in my entry point. After disabling that in that same file it worked perfectly on a expo publish ! I currently waiting for Play Store approval to see if that's working as expected but I it should be fine ! :D Thank you so much !

Comment: I get this after upgrading Expo (to 45). Trying `disableExpoCliLogging` doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue was with expo trying to put logs to non-existent route on production.
According to expo [docs](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/how-expo-works/),

> the Expo SDK intercepts calls to console.log, console.warn, etc. and posts them to the logUrl specified in the manifest.

Check if you have `Logs.enableExpoCliLogging();` enabled? Or if not, try manually importing logs at entry point

```
import { Logs } from 'expo';
```

and manually disabling them

```
Logs.disableExpoCliLogging();
```

According to the OP comment, the issue was as i mentioned. [This stack](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2623#issuecomment-441722731) helped me tho.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @Oleksii comment about checking if the Expo CLI logging where enabled with `Logs.enableExpoCliLogging();`, it seems that this was causing the issue.

Just disable those by importing `import { Logs } from 'expo';` and then calling `Logs.disableExpoCliLogging();` in the app entry point file make it works again in production environment !

Thanks again @Oleksii !